# Filtering and counting json properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, filter

I have a json object whose items I would like to analyze in js.  When I log the json to the console, you can see that it contains the element `items` which holds an array of the relevant information.

```
console.log(json)


{current_page: 1, per_page: 100, total_entries: 106, items: Array(100)}
current_page:1
items:Array(100)
0:{id: 15814, name: "Vehicle_1001", state: "available", repair_state: "broken", network_id: 99, …}
1:{id: 16519, name: "Vehicle_1002", state: "available", repair_state: "broken", network_id: 99, …}
```

However, when I try to use the `filter` function to count the amount of records where `repair_state` is `broken`, I am returned an error:

```
json.filter(value => value.items.repair_state === 'broken').length

Uncaught TypeError: json.filter is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong and how would one count the number of `items` whose `repair_state` property is equal to `broken` in this case?

Comment: Hint: `{…}  !==  […]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i see from your console.log, json is an object where items is an array inside it, so you should apply filter on the array **`items`**. It should be,

```
  var result =   json.items.filter(value => value.repair_state === 'broken').length;
```

**DEMO**

```js
var json= {
  "current_page": 1,
  "per_page": 100,
  "total_entries": 106,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "15814",
      "name": "Vehicle_1001",
      "state": "available",
      "repair_state": "broken"
    },
    {
      "id": "16519",
      "name": "Vehicle_1002",
      "state": "available",
      "repair_state": "broken"
    }
  ]
};

var result =   json.items.filter(value => value.repair_state === 'broken').length;
console.log(result);
```